# jQuery function check if value is the same as before

Tags: php, jquery

I am working with Php and jQuery.
This is my code at the moment:

```
<a onclick="getData('100')">Click here</a>
<a onclick="getData('200')">Click here</a>

function getData(number) {    
   // DO SOMETHING   
}
```

I would like to check, which was the last sending number.
For example:

```
getData('100') > call Function > // DO SOMETHING
getData('200') > call Function > // DO SOMETHING
getData('200') > call Function > // 200 was before > DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

How can I check this?
Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Can't you use array? add the numbers into array and check it?

Comment: create variable and store previous value in this variable and then you can compare previous and current value

Comment: Need more information as there are multiple ways of achieving this i.e. check contents of the getData cell, disable the button once it is clicked etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the previous call parameter in a variable, and compare it when needed :

```js
var previousParam;

function getData(number) {    
   if(previousParam && previousParam == number){
    console.log('Same number as before !');
   }else{
    console.log('New number !');
   }
   previousParam = number;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="getData('100')">Click here</a>
<a onclick="getData('200')">Click here</a>
```